# Backbone JS Models and Collection URLs

Tags: backbone.js

If I have a model named "Book" and a collection named "Library" defined as below:

Book

```
app.Book = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        title: 'No title',
        author: 'Unknown'
    }
});
```

Library

```
app.Library = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: app.Book,
    url: '/api/books'
});
```

When I call `BookInstance.save()` how does it come up with the URL to use? Does it derive it from the collection?

In `Backbone.model` there are 2 options: `url` and `urlRoot`. What is the purpose and difference between these?

In `Backbone.collection`, there is a single parameter `url`. Is this always the GET request for the RESTFUL api?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Basically, there are 3 possibilities to construct a model's url:

- If the model object exists in a collection then its `url` method will return an address composed of the `collection.url` and `model.id`: `[collection.url]/[id]`.
- If you don't want to use a model inside the collection, then `model.urlRoot`'s value can be used instead of the `collection.url` fragment, resulting in the following pattern: `[urlRoot]/[id]`.
- Finally, if you're NOT planning to persist more that one model of a given type to the server or will be defining URLs for each model upon their creation, you can directly assign a value to `model.url`.

Collections send only GET requests — to get an array of models' JSON data. For saving, removing, and updating, the individual model's `save()` (POST/PUT/PATCH) and `destroy()` (DELETE) methods are used.

[Here's the source code of `Backbone.Model.url`](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-90), which should help you:

```
url: function() {
  var base =
    _.result(this, 'urlRoot') ||
    _.result(this.collection, 'url') ||
    urlError();
  if (this.isNew()) return base;
  var id = this.get(this.idAttribute);
  return base.replace(/[^\/]$/, '$&/') + encodeURIComponent(id);
}
```

Comment: Does a backbone.model which is inside a collection use the Backbone.Collection.url property to determine the url to save, update, or remove?

Comment: It uses it for every operation.

Comment: check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17461264/backbonejs-model-url-using-collection-url). you can overwrite url settings i.e yourModel.save({ url: yourModel.urlRoot + yourModel.get("id") });

Comment: @mirrormx hey in the url function initially it is checking for urlroort of model then url of collection where is it checking for the url of model?

Answer (score 12):

In model

1. **urlRoot** is used for the Model.
2. **url** is used for the instance of the Model.

So if **urlRoot** exists
then book.fetch() will fetch the data given *id*, for example

```
var Book = Backbone.Model.extend({urlRoot: 'books' });
var book = new Book({id: 1});
book.fetch();  // will get /books/1

var Book = Backbone.Model.extend({});
var book = new Book({url: 'books/1'});
book.fetch();  // will get /books/1


var Books = Backbone.Collection.extend({model: Book});
var books = new Books({ /*....*/ });
books.fetch(); // will get /books/
```

You can refer the backbone Model urlRoot source code [here](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-urlRoot)

I hope it makes sense to you, good luck.