# What is the difference between url vs urlRoot

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

I would like to know what is the difference between using `url` or `urlRoot`. I have read the documentation ([backbonejs.org/#Model-url](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-url)), but I still feel that I lack knowledge in this area and I would like to know more. When do you have to use `url`? And in another instance when do you have to use `urlRoot`?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16862014/backbone-js-models-and-collection-urls

Answer (score 35, accepted):

`.urlRoot` is only available in a Model, and is only useful when either a model is not part of a collection, or when you want to override the `.url` property of the collection which that model is part of.

In other words, a model doesn't require neither `.url` nor `.urlRoot` property when it is part of a collection with a `.url` property set, in which case this model will use that collection's `.url` as it's own `.urlRoot`.

Here are several examples that show the difference. When you run the scripts, the http requests can be seen in browser's network panel.

*Example 1.* Post is not part of a collection. `urlRoot` defines the base part of the url. When a model is fetched, it's id is appended to the `urlRoot`.

```js
var Post = Backbone.Model.extend({
  urlRoot: 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts'
});

var secondPost = new Post({ id: 2 });
secondPost.fetch();
/*requests http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/2 */
```

```html
<script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js'></script>
<script src='http://underscorejs.org/underscore.js'></script>
<script src='http://backbonejs.org/backbone.js'></script>
```

*Example 2.* Calling fetch on a model which is a part of a collection uses the collection's `url` as the `urlRoot`

```js
var Post = Backbone.Model.extend();
var Posts = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  url: 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts',
  model: Post
});

var posts = new Posts();
posts.add({id: 2});
posts.first().fetch();
/*requests http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/2 */
```

```html
<script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js'></script>
<script src='http://underscorejs.org/underscore.js'></script>
<script src='http://backbonejs.org/backbone.js'></script>
```

*Example 3.* `url` set on a model will literally use that url for any model instance.

```js
var Post = Backbone.Model.extend({
  url: 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts'
});
var secondPost = new Post({ id: 2 });
secondPost.fetch();
/*requests http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts */
```

```html
<script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js'></script>
<script src='http://underscorejs.org/underscore.js'></script>
<script src='http://backbonejs.org/backbone.js'></script>
```

*Example 4.* `url` can be a function and it starts to make sense again.

```js
var Post = Backbone.Model.extend({
  url: function(){
    return 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/' + this.get('slug');
  }
});
var secondPost = new Post({ slug: 2 });
secondPost.fetch();
/*requests http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/2 */
```

```html
<script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js'></script>
<script src='http://underscorejs.org/underscore.js'></script>
<script src='http://backbonejs.org/backbone.js'></script>
```