# Backbone - How to populate and display Collection items from model

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a model and a collection of watchlist

```
var Watchlist = Backbone.Model.extend({
    'urlRoot': 'http://myurl/watchlists',

    'defaults': {
        id: null,
    },

    'initialize': function() {
        this.set('movies', new MoviesCollection());
    },

    'parse': function( apiResponse ){
        console.log("parsing wlist model");
        console.log(apiResponse);
        return apiResponse;
    }
});

var Watchlists = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    'url': 'http://umovie.herokuapp.com/unsecure/watchlists',
    'model': Watchlist,

    'parse': function( apiResponse ){
        console.log("parsing wlist collection");
        console.log(apiResponse);
        return apiResponse;
    }
});
```

Also have a model and a collection of Movies:

```
var MovieModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot: "http://umovie.herokuapp.com/movies",
    defaults: {
        trackId: "",
        nameId: ""
    },
    parse: function(response){
        console.log("parsing moviemodel");
        this.trackId=response.trackId;
        return response;
    }
});

var MoviesCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model:MovieModel
});
```

As you can see, the Watchlist model has a collection of movies.
How do I populate the movies collection when the watchlist model get updated? Does it populate automagically?

Also, I'm performing the following to display the movies for a specific watchlist but it's not working as expected...

```
<script type="text/template" id="watchlist-edit-template">
<h4><%= watchlist ?  'Edit' : 'Create new' %> Watchlist</h4>
<h5><%= watchlist ? '':'Enter watchlist name:' %></h5>
<textarea id="watchlistName" cols="50" rows="1"><%= watchlist?    watchlist.name : '' %></textarea>
<hr>
<div id="hiddenWatchlistId" style="display:none;"><%= watchlist ? watchlist.id : 0 %></div>
<div class="list-group">
    <% watchlist.movies.each( function( list ){ %>
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item"><%= list.get("trackName") %></a>
    <% }); %>
</div>
</script>
```

The error is "Uncaught TypeError: watchlist.movies.each is not a function"
I'm not sure how to get rid of this error...

When I display the object of the watchlist model, I receive the following:
Object {name: "Liste2", movies: Array[1], id: "563458d59f12f3030069949f"}
which let me believe the movies collection is an array instead of a collection. Am I right? How should I fix this?

I guess I do not populate properly the movies collection.

What do you think of all that?
Thanks

Comment: Look at this http://backbonerelational.org/

Comment: Have a look at a working example which is very similar to your setup here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33232006/backbone-js-fetch-json-to-model-get-returnes-undefined/33232298#33232298

Comment: Also have a look at [What is the difference between url vs urlRoot](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23510106/what-is-the-difference-between-url-vs-urlroot/33324142#33324142) as it may turn out you don't need that `urlRoot` set on your model when you already have it set on your collection.

Comment: Can you please show the code fragment that renders the template? And please remove the verbose and distracting `parse()` methods from your (first) code block - they're no-ops in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things:

1) You can pass an array of objects in the constructor call of a Backbone collection.  The collection will be created and automatically populated with instances of that collection's `model`--one for each object in the array you pass in.  So in your `initialize()` function of your `Watchlist` model, change the line

```
this.set('movies', new MoviesCollection());
```

to

```
this.set('movies', new MoviesCollection(this.get('movies')));
```

The `MoviesCollection` will take that array and populate itself with instances of `MovieModel`.

2) The automatically-instantiated `MovieModel` objects won't call their `parse` method, so you'll want to create an `initialize` method that does what your `parse` method is currently doing, e.g.

```
initialize: function(data) {
    this.trackId = data.trackId;
},
```

3) The error, `Uncaught TypeError: watchlist.movies.each is not a function` was getting thrown because `watchlist.movies` was not a collection, as you suspected, but a normal array, and therefore did not have a function called `each`.

The first 2 fixes should remedy that as well.

Here's a [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/vpxx2ny5/).

Comment: This is great help! Thaks a lot for providing this answer. I better understand the Collection initializing methods now.

Comment: I'm sorry, I disagree with point 3: from the source code given, I'd rather say the access `watchlist.movies.each()` in the template is wrong (or there's vital code missing in the question). From the shown sourcecode no one can tell where `watchlist.movies` comes from and how the OP comes to the conclusion that the watchlist model is an object with the value `{name: "Liste2", movies: Array[1], id: "563458d59f12f3030069949f"}`. Even if that object is the `attributes` object (probably it is), it shouldn't have the type `Array`. Though I agree with 1 and 2.

Comment: @try-catch-finally You are right, "from the shown sourcecode no one can tell where `watchlist.movies` comes from". But if you hit his herokuapp api, you'll see the data he's expecting, and it becomes pretty obvious how it's supposed to fit in his model-collection setup.  You are completely right with your point, "it shouldn't have the type `Array`".  Frankly, I forgot this in my answer: Since `parse` gets called before `initialize`, and he's logging the object in the `parse` method, I'd assume that that's where he's trying to insert the template--before `initialize` turns it into a collection.